# how to understand xilinx RTL schematics

Tags: fpga, xilinx, rtl

I am learning digital logic design with FPGA's, and I am using the Xilinx Spartan6 FPGA. I am able to successfully able to simulate my design correctly, but the design does not work properly, when I download it on my FPGA.

For this reason, I am trying to understand how my design is actually synthesised in order to understand what mistakes/assumptions I am making. But, I am having some problems understanding the schematics generated by the RTL Viewer

- What does each component do (Simple ones like Mmux and Madd are easy to understand, but some like LDE, are not). Is there a guide which explains what all the components actually do (I tried googling, but could not find one).
- Is there some definitive guide somewhere which explains how exactly to read and interpret these schematics ?
- What do the component names mean? (i.e I have a multiplexer named Mmux_n00341, why Mmux? why n00341? ...)

Also, is looking at the RTL schematic the best way of understanding what is happening during synthesis ?

Comment: It's probably more important to read the **entire** synthesis output and make sure you understand every error and warning and whether they affect the behavior of the synthesized design.

Comment: @ThePhoton I have no warnings in my synthesis and implementation report, and yet I do not achieve the expected results. What can be the possible reasons ? Here is the link to my files https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B9qKiyLolYedRlA4b1JjMzc5c1E&usp=sharing

Comment: This leads us to the question of what results did you expect, and how is the actual behavior different? Your code shows some styles that I wouldn't use, for example using `tick` to drive a mux in the `always @*` block instead of just using as a clock-enable input to the `always @(posedge clk)` block.

Comment: @ThePhoton I expected to get a debounced output at an FPGA pin, in response to an input at an FPGA pin, but that does not seem to happen, even though the behavioural simulation shows everything working perfectly, and no warnings in the synthesis or the implementation step.

Comment: What does the actual output look like? Is it switching at all? Or is it switching but it's also showing the glitches you were trying to eliminate by debouncing? Are you sure your real-world stimulus has similar timing to what you tested with in simulation? What is your clock frequency?

Comment: @ThePhoton the output at the output pin is not switching at all. I am working at a clock frequency of 100MHz, and this has worked for me on a couple of previous projects.

Comment: Although it's not the way I would write it, it looks to me like your code describes correct behavior. The only other thing I can suggest is to read the post-synthesis and post-p&r timing reports thoroughly and make sure there's no hidden warnings in there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36451/discussion-between-ironstein-and-the-photon).

Comment: @ThePhoton what does "Mmux_count[2]_GND_1_o_mux_17_OUT1" mean ? i.e what does each part of the name indicate ? Surely there must be a naming convention

Answer (score 2):

1. Help yourself to [Xilinx Libraries Guide](http://www-wjp.cs.uni-saarland.de/lehre/hadeprak/block_ss11/lib.pdf). LDE is a "Transparent Data Latch with Gate Enable" described on page 681.
2. This is way too broad to answer.
3. Nothing. I believe it literally means "Multiplexer number 341". The synthesizer can't provide you with descriptive names: how is it supposed to know what this mux is for in your design.

Comment: Why the name Mmux and not just mux ? (It seems to me that using Mmux and Madd should be some sort of a convention that I don't understand)

Comment: If you look at the [CLB User Guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug384.pdf), you'll see that there are dedicated structures in each slice called "AMUX", "BMUX", "CYMUX", etc. The name "MMux" may just be to distinguish your inferred mux from any of those  muxes.

Answer (score 2):

[Dmitry Grigoryev took care of it](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/220171/11683) already, but there are a few things I want to add, and since I can't comment...

First, be sure you are also carrying out a complete simulation, including timings, not just a logic one. You mention a latch in your question, be sure you actually want it in your design, because it can be a source of problems which you won't see in a logic simulation.

About the questions:

1. The synthesizer tends to squash together logic, which ends being implemented as a LUT, initialized to do a certain function. Even when you can access such initialization, it might be difficult to fully understand what's going on, since depending on the design it may be implementing a rather unexpected function. In any case, you can compare it with the simulation, specially on the registers.
2. There's no universal guide, but as with everything, you'll learn with practice.
3. The names don't have any special meaning and are generated by the tool according to some internal algorithm, for which I can't provide any detail, but in the end it's just a way for the tool to name the components.

And of course, the schematics can be useful to find problems in the design. There are two kinds of RTL diagrams: pre and post synthesis. Pre-synthesis one is easier to read, because it shows the logic functions not yet mapped to the logic in the FPGA, and is useful to trace the logic data flow.

Post-synthesis shows the components already mapped, and I've found it really useful to detect, for example, unconnected logic (which the synthesizer removes). Of course you can follow the signals too.